# Set Multiple IP Addresses For DHCP Option 6 DNS Server Using Netsh

Tags: domain-name-system, powershell, netsh

I am trying to set two IP addresses for option 6 DNS server using this code:

```
$serverIpAddress = '11.12.13.14'
$subnet = '11.12.43.33'
$value = '11.12.74.21,11.12.74.22'

netsh dhcp Server $serverIpAddress Scope $subnet set optionvalue 6 IPADDRESS "$value"
```

But am getting this error:

```
DHCP Server Scope Set OptionValue failed.
Parameter(s) passed are either incomplete or invalid.
```

How can I fix this?

EDIT:
Turns out I can get it to work by using two separate variables:

```
$serverIpAddress = '11.12.13.14'
$subnet = '11.12.43.33'
$value1 = '11.12.74.21'
$value2 = '11.12.74.22'
netsh dhcp Server $serverIpAddress Scope $subnet set optionvalue 6 IPADDRESS $value1 $value2
```

How can I make it work with one variable?

Comment: `$value = '11.12.74.21'`, `'11.12.74.22'`

Comment: @JosefZ Děkuju that works! Can you write it as an answer?